# How to combine dictionaries in Linq?

Tags: linq

I'm new to Linq.  I have code like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string,int> WordFrequency; 
}
List<Data> dataList;
```

What I want is one aggregated dictionary that does a combined WordFrequency for the whole list of Data objects.  I know how to do this using loops (iterate over the List, then iterate over each Dictionary), my question is, what is the Linq syntax for this?  Thank you.

EDIT: here is my (untested) looping approach, so you can see what I mean.

```
    public static Dictionary<string, int> Combine()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> result;
        foreach (Data data in DataList)
        {
            foreach (string key in data.WordFrequencies.Keys)
            {
                if(!result.ContainsKey(key))
                    result[key] = 0;

                result[key] += data.WordFrequencies[key];
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

So you want to flatten all dictionaries into a single one, which has no duplicate keys - of course?

You can use `Enumerable.SelectMany` to flatten all and `Enumerable.GroupBy` to group the keys.

```
Dictionary<string, int> allWordFrequency = dataList
            .SelectMany(d => d.WordFrequency)
            .GroupBy(d => d.Key)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(d => d.Value));
```

I have presumed that you want to sum all frequencies.

Comment: I see, so let me see if I have this right.  The SelectMany gives me a collection of all of the WordFrequency dictionaries.  Then GroupBy gives me a Dictionary whose key is a string, and whose value is a collection of integers.  Then the ToDictionary just runs a query on the GroupBy result to sum up all the values in the collection of integers under each key.  Is that about right?

Comment: Not quite. The `SelectMany` selects all dictionaries from all `Data` objects. The `GroupBy` projects an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` and i use it's `Key` property as key for the groups. That prevents also  duplicates in the dictionary which is created from `ToDictionary`. Each group has an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` which i use to `Sum` the values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query-based solution identical in most regards to Tim's:

```
Dictionary<string, int> allWordFrequency =
    (from d in dataList
    from kvp in d.WordFrequency
    group kvp.Value by d.Key)
       // ^^^^^^^^^ this grouping projection...
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum());
  // ...eliminates need for lambda here ^^
```

I appreciate how the two `from` clauses mimic the nested `foreach` loops in the looping-based approach of the post. Like Tim's solution, the query iterates the KeyValuePair's of the Dictionary rather than iterate the Keys collection - this way the query doesn't need to invoke the indexer to get the corresponding integer count value.